# nginx rewrite redirect rule does not work properly

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I want to redirect urls like `http://mysite.com/?action=add&goback=1` to `http://myiste.com/add/?goback=1`.

I came to:

```
location / {
    if ($request_uri ~* /\?action.*) {
        add_header Cache-Control private;
        rewrite ^/\?action=([^&]*)&?(.*)$ /$1/?$2 permanent;
    }
}
```

but it does not work and I don't see why.

P.S. I needed `add_header` just to indicate `if ($request_uri ~* /\?action.*) {` took place.
I've tried several other solutions like

```
rewrite ^/\?action=(\w+).*$ /$1/?$query_string permanent;
```

no success.

**UPDATE**:

The actual goal is:

if URL looks like this

```
http://mysite.com/add/?param1=param1&...
```

/(add)/ should become an action param:

```
location  ~ /[\-\w]+/ {
    rewrite ^/([^/]*).*$ /?action=$1 last;
    ...
}
```

this seems to be working properly and I guess I don't need extra-help with this one

if URL looks like this:

```
http://mysite.com/?action=add&param1=param1&...
```

nginx should redirect to:

```
http://mysite.com/add/?param1=param1&...
```

When I try to do this part I'm getting results I don't need - infinite redirect loops, URLs like `http://mysite.com/add/?action=add&param1=param1&...`, etc.

Is there the solution addressing my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `rewrite` only matches URI path, without query sting aka arguments, much like `location`.  Try something like this instead:

```
location = / {
    if ($arg_action) {
        rewrite ^ /$arg_action/ permanent;
    }
}
```

The `location = /` check will make sure the rule is only applied to requests to `/`, `if ($arg_action)` checks if there is `action=...` argument, and `rewrite ^ /$arg_action/ permanent;` will actually do a redirect to rewritten URI.  Query string will be preserved (as by default) from original request.

See http://nginx.org/r/rewrite for docs.

Comment: I think I'm better clarify what I actually need (the question will be updated). You answer is helpful, but I'm getting a redirect to `/add/?action=add` which is not exactly what I need.

Comment: Getting rid of `action=add` is as simple as adding a query string without `action=add` to the rewrite replacement string, and adding another `?` to avoid default query string append. Something like `rewrite ^ /$arg_action/?$newquery? permanent;` would do the trick. How to construct `$newquery` variable is left as an exercise to the reader (hint: `map $args $newquery { ~^action=add\&(?<foo>.+) $foo; }` would be a good starting point, but it doesn't cover all possible cases as usually there is no guarantee `action=` argument will be first).

Comment: Ok, thank you for a respond, now just give me some time to get around to it. It also would be nice if you'd updated your answer rather than commenting it - it is for the community - people who might want to see a complete solution in one place without bothering self to read comments.